# Generate digital JSON parameters

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, json.net

I am trying to read an Excel file where column titles are numbers like :
`25,000` - `50,000` - `75,000` ... and they can reach `1,000,000`.
Titles and values should be retrieved and filled in a JSON array as shown below:

```
{
   "Sheet1":[
      {
         "50,000":125,
         "75,000":189,
         "100,000":137,
         "125,000":45
      },
      {
         "50,000":84,
         "75,000":577,
         "100,000":154,
         "125,000":823
      }
   ],
   "Sheet2":[
      {
         "25,000":45,
         "50,000":69,
         "75,000":33,
         "100,000":48
      },
      {
         "25,000":94,
         "50,000":158,
         "75,000":572,
         "100,000":349
      }
   ]
}
```

I know how to retrieve data from Excel by sheet/column/row.
I know how to create a JSON array and iterate correctly to fill values.
BUT, I don't know how I can create an object where parameters can be like `25,000` - `50,000` - `75,000` ...

Below is my code to read the Excel file:

```
Dim xlApp = New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\template.xlsx")
Dim xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim Range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange
Dim titleArr = new List (Of String)    

For rCnt = 1 To Range.Rows.Count
   For cCnt = 1 To Range.Columns.Count
        dim val= CType(Range.Cells(rCnt, cCnt), Excel.Range).Value
        ' here I can retreive all values; 
        ' a condition can be added when rCnt = 1 fill titleArr
    Next
Next
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) classes (`JObject`, `JArray`, etc.) to create your JSON.  Here is a function which can will create a `JArray` from a worksheet.  In the function I am assuming the column headings are in the first row of the range.

```
Public Shared Function GetJArrayForSheet(Sheet As Excel.Worksheet) As JArray
    Dim array As New JArray()
    Dim Range As Excel.Range = Sheet.UsedRange
    For rCnt = 2 To Range.Rows.Count
        Dim obj As JObject = New JObject()
        For cCnt = 1 To Range.Columns.Count
            Dim key As String = CType(Range.Cells(1, cCnt).Text, String)
            Dim val As JToken = New JValue(CType(Range.Cells(rCnt, cCnt).Value, Integer))
            obj.Add(New JProperty(key, val))
        Next
        array.Add(obj)
    Next
    Return array
End Function
```

You can use the function like this to create the JSON you want:

```
Dim xlApp = New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\template.xlsx")

Dim obj As JObject = New JObject()
obj.Add("Sheet1", GetJArrayForSheet(xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")))
obj.Add("Sheet2", GetJArrayForSheet(xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet2")))
Dim json As String = obj.ToString()

Console.WriteLine(json)
```